# Is $\det(A^{-1}A)$ the same as $\det(A^{-1})\det(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Is the equation of $\det(A^{-1}A)$ the same as saying $\det(A^{-1})\det(A)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\det(AB) = \det(A) \cdot \det(B)$ for any square $A$ and $B$ of equal sizes.

Comment: Including inverses?

Comment: Yes, surely, inverse matrix is a matrix.

Comment: yes because the inverse of A is just another matrix, it doesn't have anything special , the formula given works for all matrix A and B.

Comment: Thank you! I will mark as answer in 10 minutes when it allows me to.