# If $\det A \neq 0, AB= (\det A)E_n $ then $ A \in GL_n( \mathbb Q [X])$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Is the following statement *always* true?

Let $A \in \mathbb Q [X]^{n \times n}$. If $\det A \neq 0$ and there exists a $B\in \mathbb Q[X]^{n \times n}$ with $AB= (\det A)E_n$ then $A \in GL_n( \mathbb Q [X])$.

**Note**: $GL_n(\mathbb Q)$ is defined as the set of all invertible $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb Q [X]$.

$E_n$ is defined as the identity matrix with dimension $n \times n$.

I think that the statement is true, because a matrix is invertible if its determinant is invertible over the given field. 
And in that case every determinant unequal $0$ is invertible over $\mathbb Q$.
So even without the side information with matrix $B$ it is true.

Looking at the condition $B\in \mathbb Q[X]^{n \times n}$ with $AB= (\det A)E_n$, $(\det A)E_n$ is also invertible so the statement still should be true.

**Question**: Is that guess correct?

**Note**: This question is related to that [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2345940/if-deta2-deta-then-a2-in-a-a-1-a-a-1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false. Take $n=1$, $A=(X)$, and $B=(1)=E_1$. Then $\det A=X$ and $AB=(X)=(\det A)E_1$. But $A$ is not invertible in $GL_1(\mathbb{Q}[X])$ (because $X$ is not invertible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$).

Comment: Why is $X$ not invertible in $\mathbb Q[X]$? Is it because we have polynomials here?

Comment: What do you think the inverse of $X$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ is?

Comment: $X\cdot X^{-1}=1 \cdot X^0$

Comment: $X^{-1}\notin\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Comment: because it is a polynomial? I mean $X^{-1}$ should be in $\mathbb Q$, or am I wrong?

Comment: No. Because it is *not* a polynomial.

Comment: *Of course* that $X,X^{-1}\notin\mathbb Q$.